# How to move quote in moderncv to the bottom of document

Tags: moderncv

I am using the moderncv template for my cv, and would like to move the quote to the very end of the document. Can this be achieved in any simple manner?

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\name{Some}{One}
\title{Some Title} 
\address{99, somwhere}{city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{000000}
\phone[fixed]{11111}
\phone[fax]{222222}
\email{myemail@mymail.com}
\homepage{www.mysite.com}
\social[linkedin]{me}
\social[twitter]{someone}
\social[github]{someone}
\extrainfo{more informations}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{myfoto}
\quote{some bla bla}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {\par\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}}}
\let\oldmakecvtitle\makecvtitle
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
{\let\@quote\undefined%
\oldmakecvtitle}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{First section}
\cventry{2014-2015}{Foo}{Bar}{Brest}{bla bla}{more bla bla}

\section{Last section}
\cvitem{How}{To do}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm terribly sorry I didn't see this before! Still, more than 2 years later, thank you so much :)

Comment: @4815162342 yo're welcome :-)